# Javascript to change the div color depending on the content of another

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am creating a calendar for a wordpress site and the events are created using a plugin but I want to be able to dynamically change the background color.

I want to modify the event background in the event-background div depending on the text is used in the sub div.  How can I select and modify the style using javascript.

```
<div class="event-background">

    <div class="event-place">South</div>

</div>
```

The event-place div and text are automatically generated so I can't add anything to the div attribute but the text will always either by North, South, East, West and I would like to apply a different background color for each.

I think it should be possible using If Then Else statements in Javascript but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: you'd write some code that checks the content of the inner div and apply it to the outer divs `style` property, probably the `backgroundColor` property of the `style` property would make the most sense - also, I'd use an object with property keys `North` `South` etc, with appropriate colours as values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the parent div an id such as "event-bg" as seen in the following snippet:

```
<div id="event-bg" class="event-background">
  <div class="event-place">South</div>
</div>
```

And then use this code:

```
  var backgroundRef = document.getElementById("event-bg");

  var innerDirectionText = backgroundRef.firstElementChild.innerHTML;

  switch(innerDirectionText) {
    case "North":
      backgroundRef.style.background = "green";
      break;
    case "East":
      backgroundRef.style.background = "yellow";
      break;
    case "South":
      backgroundRef.style.background = "pink";
      break;
    case "West":
      backgroundRef.style.background = "blue";
      break;
    default:
  }
```

The above code decides what the background colour should be. I just used some random background colours.

My answer does not cover any error catching or default cases and assumes that your child  will always be the first  within the parent .